# Why useState does not set the state?

Tags: reactjs

I run this code:

```
const CustomComponent = ({ initialValue }) => {

    console.log(initialValue)
    const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue)
    console.log(value)

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(value)
    }, [])

    // return JSX
}
```

The problem is that the `useState(initialValue)` seems to not work. The `initialValue` is a complex object. It's a complex JavaScript object.

Comment: Maybe, it's about how you call it. Can you provide, code block, which you used that Component?

Comment: The code you posted is not a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Make sure your code is complete so that your issue can be reproduced, otherwise others cannot possibly hope to provide an answer.